# Pandas - Storing the results of df.apply() to only select rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rather convoluted `df.apply()` to calculate the business hours between two dates.

I have it working with no issues for a single row/example, however I'm now trying to apply it across the entire df.

Example code:
`df.apply(lambda row: calc_bus_hrs(row['Created Date'], row['T1 - Date']) if not (pd.isnull(row['T1 - Date'])) else np.nan, axis=1)`

The df.apply is not relevant for every row and returns some `nan` outputs **which is fine**.

Output:

`40171         NaN
40172         NaN
40173    0.399722
40174         NaN
40175         NaN
40176         NaN
40177         NaN
40178         NaN
40179    0.017222
40180         NaN`

Now I want to save to my df using another columns value like so:

```
df[df['T1 - From'].values[0] + " Time"]
```

Now the problem is the above code fails when `df[df['T1 - From'].values[0]` contains a `nan`.

- How can I save the output to only the rows that are not nan?

Full code:

```
df[df['T1 - From'].values[0] + " Time"] = df.apply(lambda row: calc_bus_hrs(row['Created Date'], row['T1 - Date']) if not (pd.isnull(row['T1 - Date'])) else np.nan, axis=1)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with by defining a separate lambda function that can handle the row logic:

```
def lambda_func(row):
    if df['T1 - Date'] is not None:
        return calc_bus_hrs(row['Created Date'], row['T1 - Date'])
    else:
        return nan

df[df['T1 - From'].values[0] + " Time"] = df.apply(lambda_func(x))
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the premise but am slightly confused. What do I use for the `df.apply(func(x))` portion? `df[df['T1 - From'].values[0] + " Time"] = df.apply(lambda row: lambda_func(row))` fails. Sorry I am not super familiar with lambda's.